# Android Studio 4.0 Installation failed due to: 'null'

Tags: android-studio

All of a sudden I have had issue trying to install my app onto my device. I am getting a set of errors and i'm having trouble finding the solution.

**ERROR**

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\simonszarco\AndroidStudioProjects\Dartsystems\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-arm64-v8a-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'
Retry

Has anyone else come across this error before and if so how did you fix it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I changed the android skd minimum requirements to android 23 and it started working after that.

No clue why this occurred maybe someone can shed some light to this.

Answer (score 0):

I try a lot of solution and finally, I found one solution that works for me

On your mobile go to the setting of your mobile then Addition Setting -> Developer option -> and disable verify apps via USB

Then install the app. Hope it will work